# Commonly-used Predictor Function?

Tags: probability, predictive-models, politics

I was recently taking a look at some political projections (similar to the ones published by 538), and I am wondering about a particular function used to calculate the likelihood of a given party winning a political district. The function $F(p)$, defined as $$F(p) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-0.2809 \cdot p}},$$ where $p \in [-100,100]$ is the [Cook's PVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_Partisan_Voting_Index). Is this type of function – that is, one of the form $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{cx}}$ – commonly used for predicting outcomes like this?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52825/, then consider searching our site for threads about the *logit* function and *logistic regression.*