# Solving for probability with negative logits

Tags: logistic, multinomial-logit

I have a multinomial logistic regression tutorial question asking to manually solve the logits and probability. When I calculate logit for both comparisons I get negative values. How do I continue and solve for P? The question part b asks, "What is the model's prediction regarding the classification of the movie?"

If my calculations give me `model 1 P = 0.05599435837` and `model 2 P = 0.01193858104` do I do `P(Low) = 1 - (0.05599435837) - (0.01193858104) = 0.93206706059` to get the missing probability? So does 93% means the model's prediction is 93% that the movie will be classified as low revenue? 93% seems pretty skewed does it not?

[image]

I am writing my formulas as:
**model 1 - Low vs Medium**

`Movie Success = constant + 5.316*LOpening - 0.003*Theatres + 0*Rating`
`Movie Success = -7.007 + 5.316*2.4893 - 0.003*3017 + 0*1`
`Movie Success = -7.007 + 13.2331188 - 9.051 + 0`
`P = -2.8248812`

**model 2 - Low vs High**

`Movie Success = constant + 8.128*LOpening - 0.002*Theatres + 0*Rating`
`Movie Success = -18.615 + 8.128*2.4893 - 0.002*3017 + 0*1`
`Movie Success = -18.615 + 20.2330304 - 6.034 + 0`
`P = -4.4159696`

p.s. I noticed that SPSS says

> b. This parameter is set to zero because it is redundant.

I was told I could therefore discard that value. That's why I have it as 0.

Answer (score 6):

[Logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) is defined as

$$
\operatorname{logit}(p) = \log\left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)
$$

where $p$ is a probability, logit itself *is not* a probability, but log-[odds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29325/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression/29326#29326). It *can* be negative, since it potentially ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. To transform logit into probability you need to use [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) for binary classification, or [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) for multiclass classification.

Comment: So I calculated both probabilities. `P = e^-2.8248812 / (1+e^-2.8248812) = 0.05599435837` and `P = e^-4.4159696 / (1+e^-4.4159696) = 0.01193858104`. Do I just add those two together? `0.05599435837 + 0.01193858104 = 0.06793293941`? If the final `P = 67%` how do I report/express that? The probability that the move will have a low chance of success is 67%?

Comment: @TokyoToo that's not what I said. Obviously probability cannot be equal to 8.24, since probability needs to be something between 0 and 1. The values you are referring to are logits, to make probabilities of them, you need to transform them first.

Comment: I know they are logits. That's why I transformed them to probabilities. See my comment :)

Comment: You lost me in the calculations. Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression ?

Comment: I took the two logits `-2.8248812` and `-4.4159696` and used `E ^ Ln[P/(1-P)]` to transform them to two probabilities `0.05599435837` and `0.01193858104`. Then I did `P(Low) = 1 - P(Medium) - P(High)` -->> `P(Low) = 1 - (0.05599435837) - (0.01193858104) = 0.93206706059` -->> `P(Low) = 93%`. Is this correct?

Comment: @TokyoToo check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier/254071#254071

Comment: Yes, Multinomial logistic regression is known as polytomous LR, multiclass LR, softmax regression, multinomial logit etc. That's not the problem. I want to know if in my situation I am using correct calculation method. Thanks for the info Tim. I appreciate it. I will post a new question and ask a more explicit question specifically related to my calculations.

Answer (score 0):

A logit isn't the same as probability, see the definition [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/52836/291393).
There's no problem with a logit being negative, that just means the probability is lower than half.
In addition, I don't think you can calculate the logit of Low w.r.t. Medium and High together, because you'd need to know the joint probabilities. And in any case, your question doesn't ask for that.
[here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARfXDSkQf1Y&list=PLblh5JKOoLUICTaGLRoHQDuF_7q2GfuJF&index=10) a link to a bunch of videos about logits and logistical regression btw, if you want a bigger refresher and background.
Good luck with your assignment!