# I'm not sure how to interpret my binary logistic regression output from SPSS

Tags: logistic, spss, interpretation

My dependant variable is diagnosis of cancer malignant being 0 and benign being 1.  And my covariate is mean radius (of the tumour).  I get this:

```
Variables in the Equation: 

                     B       S.E.   Wald    df   Sig.   Exp(B)  95% C.I.for EXP(B)  
                                                                Lower   Upper
Step 1a radius    1.020      .104   96.518  1   .000    2.774   2.263   3.401
        Constant -15.039    1.474   104.091 1   .000    .000        

a Variable(s) entered on step 1: radius.
```

How do I interpret this in words?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Megan. Can you say more about what exactly you need help with? Is there a specific thing, or do you need a general familiarity with the concepts surrounding logistic regression? If the latter, it may help you to read my answers here: [interpretation of simple predictions to odds ratios in logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34636//34638#34638), & here: [difference-between-logit-and-probit-models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523//30909#30909).

Comment: Which parts do you need help with? The meaning of the `Step 1a radius` coefficient? What a Wald test is? What a 95% CI is? Logistic regression in general? One could easily fill a book with everything there is to understand on interpreting that output. Could you narrow the scope a little?

Answer (score 5):

The interpretation of the output is given below:

`B` - This is the coefficient for the constant (also called the "intercept") in the model.

`S.E.` - This is the standard error around the coefficient for the constant

`Wald and Sig.` - 
This is the Wald chi-square test that tests the null hypothesis that the constant equals 0.  This hypothesis is rejected because the p-value (listed in the column called "Sig.") is smaller than the critical p-value of .05 (or .01).  Hence, we conclude that the constant is not 0.

`df` - This is the degrees of freedom for the Wald chi-square test.  There is only one degree of freedom because there is only one predictor in the model, namely the constant.

`Exp(B)` - This is the exponentiation of the B coefficient, which is an odds ratio.  This value is given by default because odds ratios can be easier to interpret than the coefficient, which is in log-odds units.

`95% C.I.for EXP(B):` This is confidence interval (95%) for Exp(B), it can be anywhere between  2.263  and 3.401

Hope this helps !