# Is this definition of the Herfindahl index related to its usual definition?

Tags: econometrics, finance, coefficient-of-variation, diversity

For me, the usual definition of the Herfindahl index is this [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herfindahl%E2%80%93Hirschman_index#Formula). See also this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460564/how-is-the-herfindahl-hirschman-index-different-from-entropy?rq=1).

[Here](https://www.bankingsupervision.europa.eu/banking/tasks/internal_models/shared/pdf/instructions_validation_reporting_credit_risk.en.pdf), on page 26, it is defined as a function of the coefficient of variation:

[image]

Are these definitions of the Herfindahl index related to each other? Does anyone know an alternative source for the latter definition?

Thank you.

Comment: It helps to do a little algebra first, because you will see that $HI$ isn't really defined in terms of the CV: it's essentially a standardized version of the log variance of the $(R_i).$ The persistent logarithms make it clear it cannot be mathematically the same as the definitions you link to (which are rational functions of the $R_i,$ not logarithmic), highlighting the appropriateness of seeking some kind of *relationship* rather than an algebraic equivalence.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This possible relationship is what I am interested in. I suppose the author had something in mind when naming this index the same as the usual Herfindahl index.