# Looking for a layman's explanation of how to manually calculate log odds?

Tags: logistic, logit, logarithm, odds

I will start that I am not as math oriented as I would like to and could use a layman's / non-staticians explanation walk through of how to calculate the log odds.

I am reading Hosmer, Lemeshow, and Sturdivant's *Appliged Logistical Regression* which is helpful, but I could use a primer / tutorial to help solidify the concepts for me.

Given something like the following equation (values randomly chosen):
$$
\log\bigg(\frac \pi {(1-\pi)}\bigg) = 0.3211 + 0.27 X_1 + 0.732 X_2
$$
And the following information:

- Indicator Variable Group A $X_2 = 1$, Group B $X_2 = 0$.
- Sample Size 1000
- Likelihood Value for Model = 0.0598

How would I compute the following from the above information manually without using R or another application.

1. Log Odds for $X_1 = 3$ for each group.
2. Odds for $X_1 = 3$ for each group.
3. Probability $X_1 = 3$ for each group.

If I understand correctly the Log Odds is the $\ln(p/(1-p))$ and log-odds and odds are different; but I am *NOT clear on how to apply the above information* to calculate the above information and am looking for a step-by-step walk through that covers most of the steps required of how to apply this information and perform the calculation.

*Note: While I am utilizing this to assist me in a class it is not part of an assignment or test and the equation is made up by me purely for example purposes as I feel I am in need of a starting point example as I've spent some time reading the book (particularly chapter 3) but it is not clicking like I need it to.*

Comment: Much of what you need to know can be found in my answer here: [Interpretation of simple predictions to odds ratios in logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34638/7290).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that the "$\ln(p/(1−p))$" is the log odds.  That means all you have to do to calculate the log odds is plug in the values you want for your $X$'s and do the arithmetic.  Here is the calculation for #1:
\begin{align}
\text{log odds}(X_1 = 3; A) &= 0.3211 + 0.27\times X_1 + 0.732\times X_2  \\
                            &= 0.3211 + 0.27\times 3\ \ \ + 0.732\times 1  \\
                            &= 0.3211 + 0.81\quad\quad\ \  + 0.732  \\
                            &= 1.8631  \\
\ \\
\text{log odds}(X_1 = 3; B) &= 0.3211 + 0.27\times X_1 + 0.732\times X_2  \\
                            &= 0.3211 + 0.27\times 3\ \ \ + 0.732\times 0  \\
                            &= 0.3211 + 0.81   \\
                            &= 1.1311  \\
\end{align}
To get the odds from the log odds, you exponentiate the log odds.  That means you raise the [special number e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) ($\approx 2.718281828$) to the power of the log odds.  Here is the calculation for #2:
\begin{align}
\text{odds}(X_1 = 3; A) &= e^{1.8631}  \\
                        &= 6.443681    \\
\ \\
\text{odds}(X_1 = 3; B) &= e^{1.1311}  \\
                        &= 3.099064
\end{align}
(*Full disclosure: I used* `R` *to do the arithmetic on that one.*)

To get the probability, you divide the odds by the quantity odds plus one.  Here is the calculation for #3:
\begin{align}
\text{probability}(X_1 = 3; A) &= \frac{6.443681}{6.443681 + 1}  \\
\ \\
                               &= 0.8656579    \\
\ \\
\text{probability}(X_1 = 3; B) &= \frac{3.099064}{3.099064 + 1}  \\
\ \\
                               &= 0.7560419
\end{align}
(*I used* `R` *for this one, too.*)

Comment: OK, thanks I think this is EXACTLY what I was looking for, though I would appreciate one clarification, is the sample size and likelihood value not utilized at all in the calculations? This is one of the things I got hung up on not being able to place how it is relevant or utilized and just want to be clear on that point. Thanks, I will be sure to mark as answer too!

Comment: @CRSouser, no you don't need to use the sample size or likelihood value in these calculations.