# odds ratio vs confidence interval in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, odds-ratio

What is the relationship between the confidence interval and odds ratio of a  regression coefficient in multivariable logistic regression?

Is there  a one to one relationship? i.e. Can I measure one from the other?

Comment: See [Interpretation of simple predictions to odds ratios in logistic regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/34636/17230).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **confidence interval** aka CI (typ. at 95% ) is two numbers = (za, zb). Given an odds ratio = z, the prob that the actual z falls outside the (za, zb) **interval** is less than the (**confidence**) 95%.  You cannot measure one from the other at all. The only thing you know is that the z is inside the **interval**.

Comment: Can you confirm that from the estimated mean and variance of a regression coefficient I can not estimate the associated odds ratio?

Comment: (!) regression coefficients do not have mean or variances, they are parameters of a model that can be more or less accurate (read useful). The estimated odds ratio depends on the coeff. that is all.

Comment: This is not a proper definition of a confidence interval Jose.  In the frequentist world there is no probability associated with a parameter.  A parameter is either inside or outside an interval.  CIs deal with long-run operating characteristics.  This complexity turns many of us to Bayesian statistics.

Comment: hey don't kill the messenger: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval

Comment: The definition given in the Wikipedia article is different from yours.  It's a fine point but shows weaknesses in the frequentist approach to inference, or at least the difficulty of teaching frequentist methods.