# Observed odds ratio

Tags: regression, logistic

I have looked at the answers at:

- [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523/difference-between-logit-and-probit-models/30909#30909)
- [Interpretation of simple predictions to odds ratios in logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34636/interpretation-of-simple-predictions-to-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/34638#34638)

In a linear regression, you regress $Y$ on $X$. For each subject, $i$, you have a $X_i$ and $Y_i$.

Assuming I want to do the transformation in a logistic regression by hand, how do I obtain $P(Y_i)$ for each subject? I found the following website that goes through the procedure for categorical predictors (http://vassarstats.net/logreg1.html). Which is essentially computing the log odds for each combination of categorical predictors. How then do you deal with continuous predictors?

For illustration, I am using the dataset from:
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/

```
bindata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
```

What I would like to achieve is for the results from:

```
glm.logistic <- glm(admit ~ gpa, bindata, family = "binomial")
```

to match with

```
glm.linear <- glm(admit_transform ~ gpa, bindata, family = "gaussian")
```

where `admit_transform` is the log odds of `admit`.

The whole point of this is really to understand how logistic regression works, not as a practical way to do logistic regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a logistic regression you don't know the probability $p(x)$ of $Y=1$ given $X=x$ and hence calculation of the log odds (with the assumption that $p(x)$ is correctly specified by the logistic link) is not readily possible. How did you calculate the odds of `admit`?

To get identical results you need to calculate $p(x)$:

```
bindata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
glm.logistic <- glm(admit ~ gpa, bindata, family = "binomial")
pp<-predict(glm.logistic,type="response") #predicting p(x)
y1<-log(pp/(1-pp)) #calculating log odds
lm.out<-lm(y1~gpa,bindata) #regressing log odds on gpa
```

This will result in the same estimated coefficients.

```
> coef(glm.logistic)
 (Intercept)         gpa 
  -4.357587    1.051109 
> coef(lm.out)
(Intercept)         gpa 
 -4.357587    1.051109
```

Comment: what i understand is that there is an observed `Y` and a fitted `Y`. Observed `Y` needs to be transformed before it can be fitted i.e. for each subject, I will have a `P(Y)`. The observed `Y` would also be where the residulas come from, more specifically, there is an observed and fitted/predicted `lg(P(Y)/(1 - P(Y)))`. My question really is how do I compute this observed `P(Y)` manually in the case of continuous predictors?

Comment: Your observed data is $(X_i,Y_i)$  where $Y_i\in \{0,1\}$. You are interested in the unknown $E(Y|X=x) = P(Y=1|X=x) = p(x)$. For calculating the odds you need knowledge about $p(x)$, which you don't have but aim to estimate. The example on http://vassarstats.net is nothing more than just a toy example. 
In order to calculate $p(x)$, you run a (in your case simple) logistic regression to obtain coefficients $\alpha$, $\beta$. The estimated linear predictor is then $\eta(x) = \alpha + \beta \cdot x$ and estimated probabilites of $Y=1$ given $X=x$ are $p(x) = \exp(\eta(x))/(1+\exp(\eta(x))$.

Comment: Thanks, I am beginning to understand this better. One last question, how does the observed $Y$ come into the computations?

Comment: $Y$ enters the computations via maximum likelihood. The conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is Bernoulli with parameter $p(x)$, where, in the case of a logistic regression, you assume $p(x) = \exp(\eta(x))/(1+\exp(\eta(x)))$ with $\eta=\alpha + \beta \cdot x$ which depends on the unknown paramaters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. From this you can construct the (conditional) likelihood and maximize it w.r.t. to the two unknown parameters, using your data $(X_i,Y_i)$.