# How do you convert a log odds ratio into a marginal effect?

Tags: regression, logistic

Basically, how do you convert a one unit change in $x_1$ to a $Z\%$ change in $Y$?

Answer (score 4):

You can't (not without more information).  The point here is that the logit / logistic is not a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).  Therefore, you cannot get a constant correspondence between a starting percentage and a subsequent percentage even though you use the same log odds ratio to move from the one to the other each time.  Here are a few demonstrative numbers for $1$-unit changes in $X$ with a log odds ratio of $1$ (thus, the log odds will simply increase by $1$):
\begin{array}{c}
\text{starting %} &\text{starting lo} & &\text{subsequent lo} &\text{subsequent %} &  &\text{% difference}  \\
\hline 
0.20  &-1.37\quad &\Rightarrow  &-0.37\quad  &0.40  &  &0.20 \\
0.50  &0\quad\     &\Rightarrow  &1.0\ \      &0.73  &  &0.23  \\
0.90  &2.20  &\Rightarrow  &3.20   &0.96  &  &0.06
\end{array}

Alternatively, if you simply want to compare two groups (which could be coded $0$ and $1$, for 'control' and 'treatment'), you would need to know the base rate in the control group.

Comment: Thanks for reply! 

Yes, I am interested in comparing a control and treatment group. Assuming my data set shows a base rate of 20%, how do I convert it into marginal effect?

Comment: @YashMehta, the % difference is specific to each base rate and log odds ratio combination. You can plug in 0, and then 1, for X and solve the regression equation each time. Then pass the predicted log odds through the link function (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/34638/7290)) to get the predicted probabilities, & take their difference.